# Html2Canvas with leaflet map - not render canvas

Tags: canvas, render, leaflet, html2canvas, taint

First of all thanks for your help.
I'm using html2canvas to get an image of my app web and share it in social networks. In the app there is a leaflet map with a canvas layer but the result image is incomplete. I put option `L_PREFER_CANVAS = true;` to force canvas in leaflet map. I also have used leaflet image plugin but it only return the base map and I need legend too.

Thanks so much.

[image: Result of html2canvas]

In js

```
 html2canvas(document.body, {
      allowTaint : false,
      logging : true,
      taintTest: false,
      useCORS: true,
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        // canvas is the final rendered <canvas> element
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");  
        console.info(dataURL);          
        window.open(dataURL);
      }
    });
```

Log

[image: log html2canvas]

Comment: Is your legend inside the same map div?

Comment: The legend is created an independent div after this is added into map with this code and then is inside in map div                                                                                                                       `var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});
  legend.onAdd = function (map) {
      var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'legend');
      div.innerHTML = document.getElementById('legendMap').innerHTML;
      return div;
  };
  legend.addTo(map);`

Comment: Which version of html2canvas are you using? I was using the 5.0 and getting some issues with leaflet

Comment: I used 0.41 but not working for me, I think that my problem is proxy. I dont know what is your purpose  but maybe you can use [link](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-image) I haven't used it yet. Where are you save image map?

Comment: I'm just appeding it into a div :) Since I want the user to save the picture, I've created an URL using the canvas :D

Comment: Amm ok, I 've found this [Save map](https://github.com/tegansnyder/Leaflet-Save-Map-to-PNG) maybe I could help you. What is your problem with html2canvas?

Comment: Nice. I'll take a look on this library. The issue starts when I drag the map... I get a canvas with the dragged map and some tileLayers are missing (from OSM, for example). But I see them there on the map... I found out that if I use another htmltocanvas version it doesn't happen... but I still get some images where the layers seem not to be in the right spot :o